# How can I run a google maps request offline?

Tags: google-maps

I'm making a visualization using google maps. However, I have to make many direction requests to google maps.

Is there a way to "download" a section of a map, along with all its bus/car/bike routing information, so the direction requests can be done locally?

If it's possible, can you give a rough example to get me in the right direction?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there's no offline access to the Maps API, for either viewing tiles for associated services like routing/directions.

Additionally, you must always ensure the results of these types of requests are displayed on a Google map (which must be publicly available for free, according to the terms of service).

If you are looking for the ability to do offline routing with your own dataset, there are a number of open source routing engines available.